# replace string in more than one instance angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have the following simple html

```
<body ng-app="mainModule">
<div ng-controller="mainController">
<input type="text" ng-model="textValue" ng-change="onTextChange(textValue)"/>
{{isTextChanged|ch}}
</div>
</body>
```

Js

```
angular.module("mainModule", [])
   .filter('ch', function() {
       return function(input) {
           input = input.replace('a', '');
           return input;
       };
   })
   .controller("mainController", function ($scope)
   {
       $scope.onTextChange = function (txt)
       {
           $scope.isTextChanged = txt
       };

   });
```

The problem im facing is that angular changes only the first instance of the letter 'a'

Comment: Similar to this question,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Comment: `input.replace('a', '');` => `input.split('a').join('')`;